Peticion AJAX a un metodo en ASP.NET codebehind
Intento llamar a un metodo de mi pagina ASPX desde Javascript AJAX.
Desde Javascript logro hacer la llamada a la pagina ASPX pero el flujo empieza en el Page_Load() de Pagina2.aspx en vez de empezar en MiMetodo() de Pagina2.aspx
Lado cliente Javascript:
const misDatos = {
             "valor1": "uno",
             "valor2": "dos"
}
fetch('../Pagina/Pagina2.aspx/MiMetodo', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(misDatos), 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json()) // respuesta.
  .then(res => console.log('Respuesta: ', res))
  .catch (err => console.error('Error:', err));

Lado servidor aspx, metodo MiMetodo() dentro de Pagina2.aspx:
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string MiMetodo(string data)
{
     var jDatos = JObject.Parse(data);
     return "OK";
}

